# Ruby on Rails server requirements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server, requirements

I use rails for small applications, but I'm not at all an expert. I'm hosting them on a Digital Ocean server with 512MB ram, which seems to be insufficient.

I was wondering what are Ruby on Rails server requirements (in terms of RAM) for a single app.

Besides I can I measure if my server is able to support the number of application on my server?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how much traffic you think you need to handle. We have two machines (a 32GB RAM, usage see below) with 32 unicorn workers two serve one app with loads of traffic and we have one machine with loads of 2 worker apps that have very few traffic.

We also have to consider the database (which needs the most RAM by far in our case due to big caches we granted it). And on top of that all we have *nix which caches the filesystem in unused RAM.

Conclusion: It is very hard to tell without you telling us what sort of traffic you expect.

Our memory usage on one of the two servers for the big app: https://gist.github.com/2called-chaos/bc2710744374f6e4a8e9b2d8c45b91cf

The output is from a little ruby script I made called unistat: https://gist.github.com/2called-chaos/50fc5412b34aea335fe9

Comment: That's right. Could you please provide some reference about your `gist`, how you measure the `RAM` used by unicorn workers?

Comment: Thanks. I have 3 rails apps with very low trafic: 500/1000 visit per month. It's very low that's way I wouldn't  upgrade if not necessary.

Comment: ... and why people is downgrading this question? Is it a lame question?

Comment: @a.barbieri I don't know, maybe because of the lack of details. This question also didn't get any love http://stackoverflow.com/q/35763414/1806803

Comment: @Зелёный I updated the answer to include a link to the script :) It's a little messy.

Comment: Thanks @2called-chaos